# Getting an assertion error in mongoexport command in Mongodb.

Tags: mongodb

I am getting an error after executing this command:

```
mongoexport --db records --collection source_list --csv --out C:\bcopy.csv
```

**record** is my DB n **source_list** is my collection

It displays this message:

```
assertion: 9998 you need to specify fields
```

I also tried to specify fields but it is giving me the same error.

What changes should i make in the command to get a backup of my collection or is there any other way to do so ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's sample command that specifies fields to export:

```
mongoexport -h 127.0.0.1 --port 27018 --db mydb --collection system.profile --csv --out profile.csv --fields ns,millis,numYield,nscanned
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case --headerline helped. I had around 60 columns, enumerating them with -f would be quite cumbersome.

--headerline
If using “--type csv” or “--type tsv,” use the first line as field names. Otherwise, > mongoimport will import the first line as a distinct document.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you should be using -f paramater to choose the fields that will be exported to csv file. There is a bug reported for this case to change the explanation as the error message is not informative enough.

> https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-4224